# How to do a clean reinstall of ubuntu?

Tags: installation

If I just wipe the partition that Ubuntu is currently installed on, would that work? then just re install it onto the partition. Or is there some other process?

Comment: This _would_ work, but it is easier to have the installer wipe it out for you (choose to replace the current system when installing).

Answer (score 1):

Simply fire up a live usb and when you get to the set up screen just choose to delete current Ubuntu version and install your current version.

No need to go wiping out partitions unless you want to change the size of your ubuntu partitions

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Boot from liveCD after cliking install u can see many options....  u can find out to completely reinstall option too Good-luck

Comment: i had did this once using ubuntu 12.10 live cd it must work..